# Google sheet, keyword to return the value of the parameter of the logical expression in IF Formula?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

In IF statement is it possible to return the value of the parameter of the logical expression with some keywords instead of rewriting the parameter?

The reason is that for nested if statements it would be very useful.

I've tried to explain it as better as possible in English but I suppose that the best way is an example.

An example is:

This is using the parameter of the logical expression:

```
=IF('MySecondSheet'!C21>0, 'MySecondSheet'!C21, false)
```

This is the same but using an hypothetical keyword that I will call "this"

```
=IF('MySecondSheet'!C21>0, this, false)
```

Is it possible in some way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. In fact, I don't think it would be sensible to develop such functionality because it is a very particular use case. Suppose you were comparing with another cell value instead of a constant.

```
=IF('MySecondSheet'!C21>'MyfirstSheet'!A1, this, "text")
```

Which value would `this` refer to now? Furthermore, suppose you have a more complicated formula

```
=IF(A1 * A1 - A2 < A3, this, "text")
```

Again, it is not obvious whether `this` would return the left-hand side of the relation or one of the cell values.

Comment: I agree with you and probably my keyword wasn't the best one.

Let's say I want two keywords, one for the first parameter of the comparison and another one for the parameter on the right of the operators.

Answer (score 0):

If you name C21 in MySecondSheet `this` then something like:

```
=IF(this>0,this,"false")
```

should work.

Comment: I didn't think about this option and it's really good option, thanks. I'm going to use it in most of cases. 

Unfortunately I can't define a name for a calculation between more cells  (as the example mentioned by  @Till Hoffmann) except if I will make a calculation in a third cell and rename it.

Comment: I wanted also to highlight that it doesn't work in the perspective of dragging a formula from adiacent cells that would automatically change cells. 
For instance 'MySecondSheet'!C21 in 'MySecondSheet'!C22 if vertically.